# random button is not working as expected (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, random

ok so im working on my first project in react, and im facing trouble with random button that i created.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdxi2.png)

the random button on the navbar supposed to generate numbers and insert it to the values of the inputs, and then the block changes it color by the values.
what happens is that it generate the values to the inputs on the first click, and then on the second click it changes the block color and the inputs.
so what happens is that the inputs matches the color of the next click.

```js
export const ColorsProvider = (props) => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");
  const [red, setRed] = useState("");
  const [green, setGreen] = useState("");
  const [blue, setBlue] = useState("");
  const [colors, setColors] = useState([]);

  const changeColor = () => {
    if (
      red < 0 ||
      red > 255 ||
      green < 0 ||
      green > 255 ||
      blue < 0 ||
      blue > 255 ||
      !red ||
      !green ||
      !blue
    ) {
      console.log("Input must be between 0 and 255");
    } else {
      setColor(`rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`);
      setColors([...colors, color]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ColorsContext.Provider
      value={{
        colorValue: [color, setColor],
        redValue: [red, setRed],
        greenValue: [green, setGreen],
        blueValue: [blue, setBlue],
        colorsArr: [colors, setColors],
        clickHandler: changeColor,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ColorsContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```js
function Navbar() {
  const {
    colorValue,
    redValue,
    greenValue,
    blueValue,
    colorsArr,
    clickHandler,
  } = useContext(ColorsContext);
  const [color, setColor] = colorValue;
  const [red, setRed] = redValue;
  const [green, setGreen] = greenValue;
  const [blue, setBlue] = blueValue;
  const [colors, setColors] = colorsArr;
  const changeColor = clickHandler;

  const generateNewColorOnClick = () => {
    service.ColorsService.getRandomColor().then((color) => {
      setColor(color.color);
      let colorArray = color.color.split(",");
      setRed(colorArray[0]);
      setGreen(colorArray[1]);
      setBlue(colorArray[2]);
      changeColor();
    });
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="navbar-dark">
        <div>
          <a href="javascript:window.location.reload(true)">
            <h1>Color Generator</h1>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div>
          <a className={"href"} onClick={generateNewColorOnClick}>
            <h2>Random</h2>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

```js
function ChooseColor() {
  const {
    colorValue,
    redValue,
    greenValue,
    blueValue,
    colorsArr,
    clickHandler,
  } = useContext(ColorsContext);
  const [color, setColor] = colorValue;
  const [red, setRed] = redValue;
  const [green, setGreen] = greenValue;
  const [blue, setBlue] = blueValue;
  const [colors, setColors] = colorsArr;
  const changeColor = clickHandler;

  return (
    <div className={"home"}>
      <section>
        <div className="container">
          <div>
            <p>Choose a color</p>
          </div>
          <div className="container-box" style={{ backgroundColor: color }} />
          <div>
            <div>
              RGB <h3>between 0-255</h3>
            </div>
            <div className={"input"}>
              <input
                type="number"
                placeholder="Red"
                name="Red"
                value={red}
                max="255"
                id="redValue"
                onChange={(e) => setRed(e.target.value)}
              />
              <input
                type="number"
                placeholder="Green"
                name="Green"
                value={green}
                max="255"
                id="greenValue"
                onChange={(e) => setGreen(e.target.value)}
              />
              <input
                type="number"
                placeholder="Blue"
                name="Blue"
                value={blue}
                max="255"
                id="blueValue"
                onChange={(e) => setBlue(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <button className={"homeButton"} onClick={changeColor}>
            Click to Generate
          </button>
        </div>
        <History colors={colors} />
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but from what I can see in `ColorsProvider` you are attempting to set the `color` state and use what you think is the updated `color` state to update the `colors` state. React state updates are asynchronously processed so  in the `changeColor` callback `color` is still the current state value of the render enclosure.

```
const changeColor = () => {
  if (
    red < 0 ||
    red > 255 ||
    green < 0 ||
    green > 255 ||
    blue < 0 ||
    blue > 255 ||
    !red ||
    !green ||
    !blue
  ) {
    console.log("Input must be between 0 and 255");
  } else {
    setColor(`rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`);
    setColors([...colors, color]); // <-- color is current state
  }
};
```

You can either:

1. pass the same color value just used for `setColor`:

   ```
   const changeColor = () => {
     if (
       ....
     ) {
       console.log("Input must be between 0 and 255");
     } else {
       const newColor = `rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`;
       setColor(newColor);
       setColors(colors => [...colors, newColor]);
     }
   };
   ```
2. Use an `useEffect` hook to update the `colors` state in response to the `color` state updating.

   ```
   const changeColor = () => {
     if (
       ....
     ) {
       console.log("Input must be between 0 and 255");
     } else {
       setColor(`rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`);
     }
   };

   useEffect(() => {
     setColors(colors => [...colors, color]);
   }, [color]);
   ```

Comment: ok so first of all thanks for your help ! i appreciate that. so the first method with newColor made my code work better when i click on the "click to generate" button. but the random button still working as before. i think its something with the useState colors initialize.

Comment: @YardenYosef Interesting. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox of your code that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live? I'm also not quite understanding what the issue is with the random button, can you clarify?